# Using regular expression in Select-String

Tags: powershell

I am trying to match one or more characters using Select-String

Eg : Sourcefiles : 
a.txt 
"rent.com/room.html" 

b.txt 
"rent.com/" 

c.txt
rent.com

**Output Should be**  :
D:\test\a.txt:1:"rent.com/room.html"

**Output I am getting is  :** 
D:\test\a.txt:1:"rent.com/room.html"
D:\test\b.txt:1:"rent.com/"

**Code :**

```
$pat=@('rent.com/.\*"')
$files=Get-ChildItem "D:\test\*.*" -Recurse 
$files |
    Select-String -Pattern $pat |
    Out-File "D:\output\result.txt"
```

Appreciate your help !!

Comment: Are you intending to grab a bunch of different files? I don't see you getting the content of the files anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern is off a bit as it will get both:

- "rent.com/room.html"
- '"rent.com/"'

you likely want to revise it to be something like

`$pat='rent.com/.+"'`

an `*` says 0 or more, but a `+` says 1 or more

I'm not sure why you're making your pattern and array, and I'm not sure why you're grabbing multiple files, but not their content. Are you trying to look through a single file's content as the post suggests? If so, you're probably trying to do something like this:

```
get-content C:\myfile.txt | select-string
```

or are you trying to loop through a bunch of files and look at their name?

Comment: Thanks Sambardo . .+ works for me . 

I edited my question to clear the confusion . Yes, there could be multiple patterns and multiple files. Also from my code above, I have been able to read the content as well. I did not need to use For Loop or get-content  which is weird for me as well.

Comment: Any idea for how can I get just the matched string rather than the whole line 

Eg.
a.txt <br>
Click to get to Rent"rent.com/room.html" 

Output as:
D:\test\a.txt:1:"rent.com/room.html"

Comment: `Select-string` is designed to select the whole string if a match exists. You likely want to use the `[regex]` namespace, or `-match` with the built in `$matches` hashtable. edit: you can also call `($data | select-string -Pattern $pat).matches.value`

Comment: @Sambardo sls passes several properties down the pipe - by default  `FileName:LineNumber:Line` buit there also is matches which you can access in a follow up foreach even groups from a RegEx or context

Comment: ($files |Select-String -Pattern $pat ).Matches.Value does give me the exact match . However , I needed the filename, linenumber and line as well.  So I tried :                                                             
$files |
    Select-String -Pattern $pat |
 %{ "{0}~^{1}~^{2}~^{3}" -f $_.Path, $_.LineNumber, $_.Line ,$_.Matches }|
    Out-File "D:\output\result.txt"   . However I get an empty string  : System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match[] for the matched part. Any help  ?   As a side note , I am separating the output with '~'.